# SciPy: minimize vs least_squares for large-scale least-squares

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

I have large-scale unconstrained non-linear least-squares problem with about 300,000 residuals and 300 parameters. I wonder, which method is faster and more accurate for solving it: scipy.optimize.minimize or scipy.optimizy.least_squares?

Comment: It might be faster to try both than wait for answers here.

Answer (score 0):

[Optimization in Scipy vs Tensorflow](https://pcess.github.io/tensorflow/) - prefer NeuralNetworks (lib `tensorflow`) for Big Data